# icescrum the field startDate with value does not respect the custom validation

Tags: scrum, scrumboard

my icescrum version: **R6#14.5 Pro Standalone**

my server version: Apache Tomcat/6.0.45+dfsg

**Problem:**
When I try to close a Sprint (in Sprint Plan section) I get this error message:

> the field startDate [30/09/18 22.00] with value does not respect the custom validation

[image]

How Can I solve this issue?